# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig in Android

Tags: android, gradle, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am developing an android app. And I am using [MaxMind](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-java/) library. It basically resolves IP address to a location. This is my gradle

```
compile 'com.maxmind.geoip2:geoip2:2.8.1'
```

Gradle tasks execute fine. But when the app runs it throws an error at this line

```
public WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient.Builder(USER_ID, "lincence_key")
      .build();
```

And the error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.timelapse.ashwinxd.timelapse-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.timelapse.ashwinxd.timelapse-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

As you can see it complains about apache http client, which I don't use at all. 
Still I tried incoporating apache http client in my gradle

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

Now it throws an error at this line

```
client.city(ipAddress).getLocation();
```

with the error being

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method authenticate(Lorg/apache/http/auth/Credentials;Lorg/apache/http/HttpRequest;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)Lorg/apache/http/Header; in class Lorg/apache/http/impl/auth/BasicScheme; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
```

Again it's an issue linked to apache http client. What is the problem here?

Comment: It used by library https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/blob/master/pom.xml